# How does one set a calendar year in a fantasy world without associating it with Earth's historical technological progress?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, humans

I have a world with very rare magic which has recently invented light bulbs and steps towards running water in rural areas. I want to specify a year some ~700 years after some event but don't want the actual 700 AD Earth associated with this world as many things are different. Is there a way to specify years in a way to discourage this association (similar to Ages in Lord of the Rings) or am I overthinking this and should just go with "It's year 703"?

Comment: Couldn't you just say "It's year 703 A(fter) X" if the event is not significant to your current story?

Comment: I wanted to have some legal papers with the date indicating the previous year, so using your suggestion, "703 AX" would work?

Comment: You *are* overthinking it. ;-) Either say just "year 703" or refer it to some event, but unless the event is important, you could just leave it out. We don't go around today signing documents with date "2017 AD".

Comment: I probably am overthinking it. 703 AX is pretty reasonable and I don't really have to specify what the X means if I don't have to. One less thing to worry about :P

Comment: Brandon Sanderson's book _The Alloy of The Law_ takes place ~300 years post catacendre. And they are in the industrial age with fancy newfangled horseless carriages, lightbulbs, and a couple steel framed skyscrapers are under construction. The setting seems really solid to me, and I think you'd have to be an absolutely _awful_ writer for the fictional date to overshadow everything the main characters are seeing around them.

Comment: Calendars are fascinating but in this case I think you need to give your readers some credit. Without any other information I might associate year 700 with AD 700 but as soon as you toss in your tech I would adjust.

Comment: Dont have 7 Days a Week - this comes from the lunar movement (28 Days are a moon, 7 Days are a moon phase). Another World will have other times (maybe even more moons??)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go with "In the year 703...", and don't worry about "703 since what?" unless it's germane to your story. If you use specific dates in your story, e.g., "It was the twelfth of Selotax before he arrived at Orphenton...", you might want to add an appendix explaining the calendar - but this isn't *necessary*.

Comment: I see, I am more interested in the format of the date itself, I am writing a mystery game and one of the clues is on some legal papers. Legal papers should have a concise standard way of telling the year. Using your example, do you recommend something like "Selotax 12th, 703"?

Comment: Written date formats are entirely up to you; there's a wide variety of them - and even saying "the twelfth of Selotax" isn't the only way of giving a date; consider Roman-style dating: today (July 21, 2017 or 21 July 2017) is the twelfth day before the calends of August, and might have been written "XII d. ante cal. Aug."

Comment: I should note that any society that's advanced enough to have paperwork will likely have several different 'standard' ways of writing dates, regardless of the structure of the calendar. Some of these will be reflections of the way they're spoken, some will be for ease of reading, and some will be for ease of organizing, especially when you get to mechanical processing of data. For your story, the actual format won't truly matter, as long as you use it consistently - and even then, different writers writing to the same person may use different formats...

Answer (score 3):

Calendaring and date-keeping systems are fascinating subjects so no, you are not over thinking it.

1. Years after the start of the reign of a sovereign. If your date system accepts a lunar/solar "year" with a start and finish, then you can have the year be "X years after Leader So-and-so took the throne."
2. Years after an event. This is good for establishing your world experienced something of major importance and it can be a plot point.
3. If your world is very politically stable you can have years number from the start (or supposed start) of a kingdom or empire. The higher the number the longer the elite have been in power.
4. If your place/planet has a strange seasonal pattern your years may be grouped into pairs or more. Cold Year/Hot Year, Dark Year, Normal Year, Bright Year, etc.
   Remember: Call a year a year. Years do not need twelve months or four seasons. People from different areas may have different calendars.

Comment: On the subject of sovereign reigns, Japan tends to name a new historical period everytime a new Emeperor assumes the throne.  This is not named after the Emperor, who during his reign is never refered to by his given name.  The current emperor is Akihito and the current period is the Heisei period.  During his reign, Akihito is "The Emperor" as his official name.  Upon his death (or retirement) he will be renamed to (Retired) Emperor Heisei and a new period will be declared.  Essentially, in death, it loosly is Emperor during the Heisei Period.

Comment: This is informal with other national soveriegns too.  America often refers to the bulk of the 80s as "The Regan Years" while England calls the same period "The Thatcher Years" (it's the Showa period in Japan). But its less formally codified.  This system works better with Autocratic governments, as the ruler is in office for a longer period of time... But term limits might work as it codifies a specfic period of time a little better.

Answer (score 2):

I like Jeff's answer, but!

Having a calendar that is 700 years old strongly implies that *some* event happened that was so important that all other events are relative to it, at least in the eyes of in-universe scholars and political leaders.

That's a huge piece of world-building! The nature of that event, and the manner in which you disclose (or fail to disclose) it is going to have far-reaching creative consequences.

All from one one number! :)

Answer (score 1):

All times are given in reference to some specific event.  Our [current counting scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domin), despite the new, politically-correct designations of CE or BCE,  is dated from the birth of Jesus Christ (who was born about 4bc due to a counting error.)

Most kingdoms either dated from the start of the rule of a king or from their founding.  The J[ewish year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) is based on the date of creation

"In the fourteenth year of Larry the King, the 30th king since the great trouble..."  "Now, 703 years past the migration"  "Now, in the 1,239th year of the great teacher, Bob."

Answer (score 0):

A calendar is merely a way of tracking macro-time.  The first development is to reasonably determine how many unites and how divided and by looking at multiple objects in the sky.  They tend to be solar (the Julian calendar is based on the revolution around the sun), lunar (the Jewish calendar is based on the phases of the moon), or stellar in nature (the Greek Zodiac is based on the time when certain constellations are visible).  What is remarkable is that most calendar systems

The calendar as we know it is the Gregorian which is based on the Julian calendar (the first month was March).  The first 4 months (March, April, May, June) honored gods and goddesses, then month namers got lazy and named the next couple of months after their order in the rotation (Quintilis, Sextilis (more on these two in a moment), September, October, November, December).  The final two were symbolic.  The 11th month was named after Janus, the two faced god who was the god of passages and the change in time.  The two faces are looking at both the past and the future and signal a period of reflection of the old year and the anticipation of the new.  February was named after a festival about forgiveness and mercy and was essentially the Dickus Claudius's Swing Roman New Year's Rockin' Eve (Live from the Coliseum).

Julius Caesar, for his part in the reform, wanted people to remember he had a hand in their new calendar (and possibly because he was sick of the Senate forgetting his birthday after he dropped several hints that year about how he really wanted a new knife) so he renamed Quintilis to July.  His son, not to be outdone by Papa Caesar named the following month in to remind people he came after Caesar (and possibly improve his odds with the ladies by association with the Sextilis).  The Gregorian calendar a series of reforms from Pope Gregory XIII to better track Easter by reforming the lunar calendar.  (Remember, the Last Supper was Passover, so it had to be close to Passover, which was always the first full moon after the first day of Spring.  Easter is the first Sunday after the First Full Moon after the First day of spring.)  And moved the New Year to better correspond with the year tracking corresponding to the Nativity of Jesus, which had been established in the 8 century AD.  (Ironically, given regional shepherd seasonal patterns in Israel, it's now widely believed Jesus' birth was closer to March than December and in what is now 3 A.D.  ... Whoops!)  In addition, Gregory took the fact that everyone was already going to be confused and declared the day after October 4, 1582 (Julian calendar) was now October 15, 1582 (Gregorian calendar), marking the first known time in history that people had such a crazy time in the 80s, they lost time.  This only effected Roman Catholic European countries, as Protestant and Eastern Orthodox (Byzantine) countries still ran on Julian calendar, but had Gregorian calendar for international trade purposes and official documents had two dates wit O.S. and N.S. denoting the old style and new style date.  Over time, the number of countries that used Gregorian calendar outnumbered the Julian calendar users and the latter switch the former for convince.  All of this was to make a 0.002% correction to the year length.  Pope Gregory XIII concluded that such an overall change does not merit getting a month named after you (and that Gregtober sounded stupid) and was content to have his name on just the system.

Why is all of this relevant:  To show you that while the math of the days, weeks, months, and years is largely sound... most calendars were pretty close on the number of days in a year... It's pretty impressive that they found in 1582 that the year was off by 0.002%... but that the numbers involved do not divide well...  The numbers are fixed to circular motions which means you'll have to use inconsistent division of periods to fix the issue.  As long as you're correct in the tracking the change of time, you can name and set up a calendar of your own choosing.  As my injection of humor (or attempt to do so) is meant to show, the calendar names are largely arbitrary and were put in for often cultural significance and symbolism, laziness, and most importantly pettiness.  Hey, if you can declare the 5-14th of a month no longer exists for one year only, you're not dealing with a naming system built on logic... even if it corrects a logic mistake.

For theory purposes, you can add an entire month by making each month a series of four 7 day weeks, provided you include an additional leap-week once every 28 years so long as you watch out for that lousy Smarch weather.

Comment: @can-ned_food:  Meant was "how many units and how to divid into smaller units".

Comment: @can-ned_food Also, thanks for correct spelling of the months now know as July and August... was doing those two from memory and really didn't care to get them right...

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is by just saying "Planet X has rotated around the Local Star 700 times since...." or even simpler, "700 Winters have passed since...". If you are just referencing date from an event there is no need to create an entire calendar.